# How to use field mapping for nested object in ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two objects below,

```
let response = {
                offer: {
                    custom_fields: {
                        job_title: 'engineer'
                    },
                    starts_at: 'test',
                    job_post: 'test'
                }
            }

let defaultFieldMapping = {
                "$.engagementData.title": {
                    default: "Software Engineer",
                    path: "$.offer.custom_fields.job_title",
                    fieldName: 'Title'
                },
                "$.engagementData.startDateUTC": {
                    default: null,
                    path: "$.offer.starts_at",
                },
            }
```

Need to form new object and expected result like below

```
let expectedResult = [
                {
                    externalFieldId: '$.offer.custom_fields.job_title',
                    integrationFieldId: '$.engagementData.title'
                },
                {
                    externalFieldId: '$.offer.starts_at',
                    integrationFieldId: '$.engagementData.startDateUTC'
                },
                {
                    externalFieldId: '$.offer.job_post',
                    integrationFieldId: ''
                },
            ]
```

integrationFieldId is empty string because that's not exists in the defaultFieldMapping path column.

Comment: What should the logic behind this be? Why are there 3 objects in the result?

Comment: You need `deepObjectKeys` and then just `map` it

Comment: @Reynicke look at response  there are only three field with value (job_title, starts_at, job_post)

Comment: I hoped to nudge you to the right direction. When the values are in the response object, you need to iterate this. Generating the values for ``externalFieldId`` is a bit tricky. You could use this: https://gist.github.com/ClementParis016/c3cc7cec0477eeeda5f90054ebbe32aa

Answer (score -1):

```
function getDeepKeys(obj) {
  function* _getDeepKeys(obj, prefix) {
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (typeof v === 'object' && v) yield* _getDeepKeys(v, `${prefix}${k}.`)
      else yield `${prefix}${k}`
    }
  }
  return [..._getDeepKeys(obj, '$.')];
}

console.clear()
console.log(getDeepKeys(response))
console.log(
  getDeepKeys(response)
    .map(externalFieldId => ({
      externalFieldId,
      integrationFieldId: Object.entries(defaultFieldMapping).find(([k, v]) => v.path === externalFieldId)?.[0]
    }))
)
```